# ActiveRelation that requires nested joins using scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, join, nested

I am new to rails. Having a blast. The query API though is giving me
some trouble. I've been zooming and doing a lot of stuff very quickly,
but this is the first time I have spent hours trying to figure it out.
It's not like anything I've used before - regular SQL, or Hibernate,
or whatever.

The model I have is pretty simple.

- A PrivateMessage has many Recipients
- A Recipient has a Receiver (which of class User)

  - recipient also has fields for 'is_read' and 'is_deleted'

My goal is to build a query that finds all the unread and not deleted
private messages for a given user. To accomplish this, we need to join
'private_messages' to 'recipients'... and then 'recipients' to
'users'.

Here's the relevant User model code:

```
has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'PrivateMessage', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
has_many :recipient_of_messages, :class_name => 'Recipient', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'

scope :by_id, lambda { |id| where(:id => id) }
```

My Recipient model has the following relevant code:

```
belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
belongs_to :private_message

scope :unread, where(:is_read => false).where(:is_deleted => false)
scope :by_receiver_id, lambda { |id| Recipient.joins(:receiver).merge(User.by_id(id)) }
scope :unread_by_receiver_id, lambda { |id| unread.by_receiver_id(id) }
```

When tested in isolation, this works 100%.

However, when I code the private message queries, I run into problems.

```
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
has_many :recipients, :class_name => 'Recipient'

scope :sorted, order("private_messages.created_at desc")
scope :non_deleted, where(:is_deleted_by_sender => false)
scope :non_deleted_by_sender_id, lambda { |id| sorted.non_deleted.joins(:sender).merge(User.by_id(id)) }

# this scope does not work
scope :non_deleted_by_receiver_id, lambda { |id| sorted.joins(:recipients).merge(Recipient.by_receiver_id(id)) }
scope :newest, sorted.limit(3)

# this scope does not work either
scope :newest_unread_by_receiver_id, lambda { |id| newest.joins(:recipients).merge(Recipient.unread_by_receiver_id(id)) }
```

When I try and use 'newest_unread_by_receiver_id' or 'non_deleted_by_receiver_id', I get the following exception:

```
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'receiver' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

This doesn't make much sense to me... because if the name was spelled
wrong, why doesn't it fail when I test it isolation?

Can someone help me out please? This one is driving me nuts. At times
like this, I just want to program in full sql or Hibernate QL so I could just be done with it :(

If I'm just approaching the problem totally wrong, then I'd appreciate it if you just let me know that too. I am under the impression that using scopes and ActiveRelation was the way moving forward in Rails 3.1.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this "all the unread and not deleted private messages", because `is_read` and `is_deleted` fields seem to be in Recipient model instead of PrivateMessage. What makes private message deleted?

Comment: The private message is never deleted - it can't be. If the sender of a message or one of the recipients deletes the Private Message shared by all of them... then everyone's copy would be deleted. This is not good. By simply storing a boolean called 'is_deleted' for that receiver in the Recipient class, that private message can be hidden (i.e. deleted) for that user but still be shown for the other users. If the sender and all the recipients delete it, then we can finally delete the PrivateMessage out of the database - but only at that time.

Comment: PrivateMessage also has is_deleted as well to track if the sender deleted it from their sent box. PrivateMessage also has a :sender attribute as well, but I omitted it for simplicity sake since it wasn't important to this query that I'm trying to get to work.

Comment: Btw.. you seem to be using `merge` quite a lot? I can't find any examples from the documentation for that.

Comment: I don't think joins() with merge() is meant to be called more than once. I don't see why... it would enable mass reuse of scopes. That's honestly the most intuitive way to have designed this API... make it work for N-level deep cases and not just 1-level deep cases. Since I assumed that was how it worked, I got burned. They should probably mention this limitation in the documentation. That's basically what burned me :(

Comment: But I can't find single example that uses `merge`.. :)

Comment: Ahaa, now I found something: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: Updated the answer example with scope/merge.

Comment: Your example scope `scope :by_receiver_id, lambda { |id| Recipient.joins(:receiver).merge(User.by_id(id)) }` might work without `Recipient.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use something like this. I kept scopes separate for clarity.

**Models** (renamed PrivateMessage -> Message and Recipient -> MessageCopy):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => :sender_id
  has_many :sent_message_copies, :through => :sent_messages, :source => :message_copies
  has_many :received_messages, :through => :received_message_copies, :source => :message
  has_many :received_message_copies, :class_name => "MessageCopy", :foreign_key => :recipient_id
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :message_copies
  has_many :recipients, :through => :message_copies
end

class MessageCopy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User"
  scope :unread, where(:read => false)
  scope :undeleted, where(:deleted => false)
  scope :sent_to, lambda { |recipient| where(:recipient_id => recipient.id) }
end
```

**Schema** (migrations would have taken too much space here):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110503061008) do
  create_table "message_copies", :force => true do |t|
    t.boolean  "read",         :default => false
    t.boolean  "deleted",      :default => false
    t.integer  "message_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
  end
  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
  end
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
  end
end
```

--edit

**Example query using joins returning messages**

```
Message.joins(:message_copies).where(:message_copies => {:read => false, :deleted => false, :recipient_id => 3})
```

**Message scope reusing scopes on other model**

```
scope :non_deleted_by_recipient, lambda { |recipient|
  joins(:message_copies).merge(MessageCopy.unread.undeleted.sent_to(recipient))
}
```

--edit2

This Railscast has nice examples of both joins and scopes:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: Unfortunately, your query only gets the list of recipients, which my code already does :( I basically want to do a double join, not a single join. I can get the single join to work already (it's above). We need to go from Message<->MessageCopy<->User... and we need to get Messages back. For some reason, this doesn't work. Is this just a limitation with Rails? Do they not expect us to do this? If so, I have to ditch Rails and go back to Java asap :( I will eventually need to write queries that do 7 or 9 joins. If it's having problems with 2, I am in trouble.

Comment: I also want to add that I do not want to start from user - I do not want to load the user, or the message copies - I only want to load the messages. I don't want to make the extra calls to the database by getting the message copies - just the messages ;P

Comment: Of course you can write pure sql queries with Rails if you want to :). I'm just wondering what is the use case that this example can't handle?

Comment: I'd like to find out in theory why mine does not work, just so I can learn. When we make calls to the database, we should only get the info we need and nothing else. There's no point in wasting system resources if we don't have to. I hope I don't have to drop down to sql just to do 2 sql joins. That's not very good at all... Hibernate in the Java world can do 70 table joins for example and not complain. All I want to do is load all the messages that belong to a user that have not be read and not deleted by them, while not loading the message copies out of the database.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is very easy to write in hql. Writing the query would take about 60 seconds, not 5 hours :( "select privateMessage from PrivateMessage privateMessage join privateMessage.recipients recipient where recipient.userAccount.id = ? and recipient.isRead = false and recipient.isDeleted = false order by privateMessage.creationDate desc"

Comment: Have you checked Rails Guides part on joins? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables . I tend to complicate things only after I find it is really necessary thing to do.

Comment: Yep. One of the first places I looked when I was googling (I did lot of searching before I posted here). They only give examples where they join 1 table. They never join more than one. I don't want to sound negative... but I don't see how I can use Ruby/Rails if I can only join 1 table. I don't think it's possible to write complex applications with this limitation :( I am more disappointed because if this is true, then I have wasted a few days for basically nothing :(

Comment: Join only one table?. I can see multiple associations: `Post.joins(:category, :comments)`,  nested associations: `Post.joins(:comments => :guest)` ...

Comment: This might work like you intended: `Message.joins(:message_copies).where(:message_copies => {:read => false, :deleted => false, :recipient_id => 3})`. I don't see the need for joining users table though.

Comment: Added some examples to answer.

Comment: Yep, that one works. Believe it or not, I discovered that just 10 minutes ago, and I just refreshed my browser now. I should have refreshed it 40 minutes ago to save me the trial and error ;) LOL. That's exactly what I did as well. I guess re-using the scopes is a wasted effort. I am not going to bother anymore. On the net, they advocate reusing the scopes and they say it's super cool to chain them together... but it doesn't work for complex queries. I think using 2 joins()/merges() causes it to bomb. I guess I'll have to use the alternate syntax. Wish the docs said this :(

Answer (score 2):

Eventhough you seem to have found an answer I would like to show you how i have done it in my application:

```
message table:
id, sender_id, recipient_id, conversation_id, sender_deleted_at, recipient_deleted_at, title, body, (whatever you like)

conversation table:
id, sender_id, recipient_id, conversation_id, sender_deleted_at, etc.

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  has_many :conversations
  has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sender_id", 
                           :conditions => "sender_deleted_at IS NULL", :dependent => :destroy, :order => "created_at DESC"
  has_many :recieved_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "recipient_id", 
                            :conditions => "recipient_deleted_at IS NULL", :dependent => :destroy, :order => "created_at DESC"
  has_many :created_conversations, :class_name => "Conversation", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :recieved_conversations, :class_name => "Conversation", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
  belongs_to :conversation

  before_create :assign_conversation
  after_create  :save_recipient, :set_replied_to, :send_receipt_reminder
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"

  has_many :messages

  scope :conversations_for_user, lambda {|user| {:conditions => ["sender_id = :user OR   recipient_id = :user", :user => user] }}
end
```

This way you can fetch pretty much anything and it also enables you to display messages as conversations. You can fetch unread messages in the current conversation, you can fetch all messages for a given conversation or user, etc. etc.

Also you only have one record for every message which seems like a nice solution. I can also give you the additional methods in case you dont want to write them yourself.

Regards
Stefano

PS: dont just copy-pasta my code I might have some spelling mistakes in it. Didnt have time to proof, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Related: https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/pull/5494