# How to properly nest joins with merges in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, subquery

```
class Customer

  scope :active_whole_year, -> { joins(:subscription => :subscription_type).merge(Subscription.active_whole_year) } 

end


class Subscription

  scope :active_whole_year, -> { joins(:subscription_type).merge(SubscriptionType.whole_year) }

end


class SubscriptionType

  scope :whole_year, -> { where(:name => WHOLE_YEAR) }

end
```

Calling Customer.active_whole_year gives the following error:

```
Association named 'subscription_type' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

..for some reason.

I can get `Customer.active_whole_year` working by removing the joins condition from the `Subscription.active_whole_year` scope. But then, calling `Subscription.active_whole_year` directly won't work, since it relies on that condition for the following merge to work.

I know I can solve this by simply making the scope `Customer.active_whole_year` into one huge direct query. The thing is, I want the scopes to work individually, but also be able to nest them, like I'm trying to do here. This is to separate concerns, and to keep the code DRY.

So how do I properly nest the joins and the merges, so that `Customer.active_whole_year` uses `Subscription.active_whole_year` and that the latter can be called independently as well?

Is this at all possible in an elegant way in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

I found this is an issue with how Rails doesn't preserve join context when merging nested queries:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3002
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5494#issuecomment-5530297

Related SO question:
[ActiveRelation that requires nested joins using scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865426/will-you-please-help-me-with-a-activerelation-that-requires-nested-joins-using-s)

It's apparently fixed in this Rails commit:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/dc764fcc

Seems the solution is to upgrade to Rails 4.0.2. Too bad I'm forced to use Rails 3 because of active_admin...

Comment: I'm having this issue in rails 4.0.2 as well.  I've added a gist to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3002.  Maybe I can dig into it after finals are done...